# How to create login endpoint for serverless app with aws cognito service?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework

I need to create login endpoint using cognito and serverless framework, i already created signUP and confirm email endpoints, but whatever i do with logIn endpoint i get error `"message": "Internal server error"`. I try everything but still get this error. Help me, please.

This is my login endpoind code:

## userSignIn.js

```
'use strict'

const Responses = require('../common/api_responses');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({apiVersion: '2016-04-18'});
const cognitoUserPoolClient = process.env.cognitoUserPoolClient

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback){

  const user_data = JSON.parse(event.body);

  var params = {
    'AuthFlow': 'ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH',
    "AuthParameters":{
      "USERNAME": user_data.email,
      "PASSWORD": user_data.password
    },
    "ClientId": 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    "UserPoolId": 'us-east-1_XXXXXXX'
  };

  cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminInitiateAuth(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      return Responses._400({err});
    }
    else{
      callback(null, Responses._200({data}));
    }
  });
};
```

Config file :

## serverless.yml

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221
  profile: testSLSBlogApi
  region: us-east-1
  stage: dev
  environment:
    tableNamePost: ${self:custom.tableNamePost}
    imageUploadBucket: ${self:custom.imagePostsBucket}
    region: ${self:provider.region}
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:*
        - s3:*
        - ses:*
      Resource: '*'
functions:
  userSignUp:
    handler: lambdas/endpoints/userSignUp.handler
    events:
      - http:
         path: sign-up
         method: POST
         cors: true
  confirmSignUp:
    handler: lambdas/endpoints/confirmSignUp.handler
    events:
      - http:
         path: confirm-email
         method: POST
         cors: true
  userSignIn:
    handler: lambdas/endpoints/userSignIn.handler
    events:
      - http:
         path: sign-in
         method: POST
         cors: true
resources:
  Resources:
    ImagesPostBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: ${self:custom.imagePostsBucket}
    MyDynamoDBTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        TableName: ${self:custom.tableNamePost}
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: ID
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: ID
            KeyType: HASH
        BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
    CognitoUserPool:
      Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
      Properties:
        UserPoolName: ${self:provider.stage}-user-pool
        UsernameAttributes:
          - email
        AutoVerifiedAttributes:
          - email
        Policies:
          PasswordPolicy:
            MinimumLength: 6
            RequireLowercase: False
            RequireNumbers: True
            RequireSymbols: False
            RequireUppercase: True
    CognitoUserPoolClient:
      Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient
      Properties:
        ClientName: ${self:provider.stage}-user-pool-client
        UserPoolId:
          Ref: CognitoUserPool
        ExplicitAuthFlows:
          - ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH
        GenerateSecret: false
```

This object i use for returning responses from lambdas handlers:

## api_responses.js

```
const Responses = {
  _200(data = {}){
    return {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      },
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    };
  },

  _400(data = {}){
    return {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      },
      statusCode: 400,
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    };
  },
};

module.exports = Responses;
```

Comment: See error detail in Cloudwatch log.

Comment: in cloudwach there is any eror, only id of the request without any details